# Is it correct to use multiple OR conditions in one if statement, what are alternatives?

Tags: java, if-statement, conditional-statements

I would like to know which way is more suitable and efficient in achieving something like: checking if text was entered in a field

```
if(text1.equals("") || text2.equals("") || text3.equals("") || text4.equals("")) {
  //Do Stuff
}
```

I can see how this gets messy quickly with more than 2 fields, and would like to know if this is a correct way to do this, or do alternatives exist?

Comment: how about a case statement?

Comment: If you can store your fields in a `List` or `Map` then just loop. Then with Java 8 you can `stream()` that collection and use a lambda. Without knowing the general structure of your code we cannot recommend what changes you could make to simplify your code.

Comment: Side note: It would be better to use `"".equals(text1)` (and so on), to avoid `NullPointerException`s :)

Comment: Well, if you use Java 6+ you can replace that with `text1.isEmpty()`... Not that this answers your question.

Comment: @BackSlash How is that better?

Comment: how about a function? you could handle exceptions too!

Comment: A question is where you use that statement; is that in a loop?

Comment: I had the same problem I made a StringUtils class which contains a method isEqualsAny(string checked, string...args) which check inside a for if any of the args equals to the checked string. It might be useful if you have to do that check in multiple places.

Comment: @fge no simple if condition inside a method, not looping.

Comment: @Boann It was a suggestion, because doing like I suggested will avoid `NullPointerException`s if `text1` (and all others) is `null`

Comment: @BackSlash I see that. I just don't see how suppressing exceptions makes things better, or how allowing null or *non*-empty input is likely to be useful.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
if (Arrays.asList(text1, text2, etc).contains(""))
```

But a better solution would depend on the context.

Note however that this is  a little slower than your current code. If you don't execute that test a bazillion times a second, though, it should not matter.

---

**EDIT** since it has been learned in the comments that strings with only spaces should also satisfy the condition... Here goes:

```
private static final Pattern PATTERN = Pattern.compile("\\s*");

private static boolean emptyOrSpacesOnly(final String... strings)
{
    for (final String s: strings)
        if (PATTERN.matcher(s).matches())
            return true;
    return false;
}
```

Then, in code:

```
if (emptyOrSpacesOnly(text1, text2, etc))
```

Comment: Neat solution. Before the OP panics, perhaps I'll point out that it's *very* unlikely there will be any problems due to the code being fractionally slower. Don't want to encourage any premature optimisation here :-)

Comment: I tested the code and was able to bypass the check by entering spaces in the fields, I know this is not exactly what my question states, but is there a way to check that text was entered not just empty or space?

Comment: Or using JDK 8: `Stream.of(text1,text2,text3).anyMath(text -> text.isEmpty())`.

Comment: @Ilja you did not mention that in the question!

Comment: @EdwinDalorzo I don't like how Java 8 examples make me feel like I need to learn the language again :-D

Comment: @EdwinDalorzo is `anyMath` right or should it be `anyMatch`?

Comment: @gla3dr It is a typo, it should be `anyMatch`.

Answer (score 3):

[fge's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22460165/474189) is certainly clever and reduces the lines of code. However, I feel some of the meaning is lost when glancing at that snippet of code.

I would encourage you to embrace readable code, even if it's slightly more verbose. My solution would be to test these preconditions before beginning a method. If the precondition fails, throw an exception.

Either write your own validation methods or use something like Apache Commons Lang [`Validate`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.3/org/apache/commons/lang3/Validate.html) class. Then your code would look something like:

```
Validate.notEmpty(text1, "error message");
Validate.notEmpty(text2, "error message");
Validate.notEmpty(text3, "error message");
Validate.notEmpty(text4, "error message");

// This line is only reached if all fields are non-empty
```

I think this is easy to read, which is half the battle won.